# Freemember Login No Errors or login - Solved

Tags: structure, login, freemember

I'm lost, this should be easy but for some reason it's not.

If I use the default EE login tags it's fine, replace with Freemember Tags and BAM the whole shebang fails to work, no errors, no nothing :(

I could've sworn it worked originally, I styled the error tags and everything. 64 Char encryption key…

Running EE2.4

Freemember 2.2.2

Structure 3.2.3

```
{exp:freemember:login return="members-area"
          form_class="login"
          error_handling="inline"
          error_delimiters='<span class="error">|</span>'}

        <div class="wrapper">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
            {field:username}
            {error:username}
        </div>
         <div class="wrapper">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
            {field:password}
            {error:password}
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
        </div>
     {/exp:freemember:login}
```

This page is controlled by Structure which shouldnt matter as it works for the native EE login tag :(

Any pointers ?

Comment: Nothing looks obviously wrong with your code, but I'd follow Jamie's advice below and see if there are some errors you are getting which aren't being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the culprit, a rougue htaccess rule: RewriteEngine On was commented out, uncomment and we're golden, apologies :)

Comment: Nice catch! Remember to mark your answer as "accepted" using the check button on the left to let others know the problem is solved (you may have to wait 48 hours after asking your question to do this).

Answer (score 2):

If you remove this parameter -

```
error_handling="inline"
```

you should see what default errors are causing the login to fail in the default EE error page - should help you fix the error.

Comment: Absolutely nothing displays, no errors the page just refreshes . If use ee login tags I get the error page